# What plug-in do I need to play Spiral Knights?

Tags: spiral-knights

Basically, the internet provider for the hotel I'm staying won't let me run Steam, so I can't play Spiral Knights through there. I've been trying to run it through Kongregate, but every time I try to launch the game, I get this error:

[image]

I'm using Chrome and I have Java fully updated, as well as Shockwave Flash, so I'm at a loss as to what I'm missing. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: does the Java icon show up in your taskbar when you try to run the game?

Comment: As far as I know it only takes Java, but also be aware that if you play it on Kong you can't access your Steam character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you are getting this notification:

[image]

Click it.

If not, try following these [instructions for the Chrome Java plugin](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95697).  Uninstalling/Reinstalling sometimes mysteriously fixes things.

Comment: The instructions are what got it for me. Thanks, Origami.